# Tensorflow: Prediction of float value from image always returns 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a model as follows:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D

model = keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(480, 640, 3), data_format="channels_last"),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(480, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation="relu")
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 3
model.fit(
    x=train_images,
    y=train_values,
    epochs=epochs
)
```

The variable `train_images` is an array of PNG images (640x480 pixels) and `train_values` is an array of floats (e.g: `[1.11842, -17.894, 2.03, ...]`.

**My goal** is to predict the float value (at least, to find some approximate value), so I suppose that MSE should be the loss function in this case.

However, after training the model, I only get zeros not only with `model.predict(test_images)` but also with `model.predict(train_images)`.

**Note**: I have to recall that my batch contains only 37 images, and my test sample contains 14. I know that the size is ridiculous, but this script is just a concept for something bigger.

If it helps, here is the result of `model.summary()`:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 480, 640, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 240, 320, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 240, 320, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 120, 160, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 120, 160, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 60, 80, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 307200)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 480)               147456480 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 481       
=================================================================
Total params: 147,480,545
Trainable params: 147,480,545
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Remove relu from your output layer...

Comment: @xdurch0 Yes, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with change your activation function, relu limits values so anything below 0 = 0, thats not desire-able

Secondly normalize your y values, as it stands your values could be anywhere from -inf to +inf, range normalize them and store the normalization parameters. At run time you could always reverse this and get actual values

Also pump up the epochs, with that small a train set i suggest try overfitting the network, if a network overfits it will most likely train well

For now try these suggestions out, i think normalization is quite important

ALSO :: I suggest make the network much deeper, you need to extract the shapes and textures in the image and your network might not be deep enough (or as a matter of fact even be dense enough) to do that. I suggest use keras to load a pre trained model like VGG16, strip the head off add regression layers and transfer learn it onto your dataset. That could be better

Comment: Thanks so much. In fact, the code `activation="relu"` of the last layer is the problem. Also, I will experiment with your suggestions and check if I get better results :)